# jQuery Sorting prevent outer div sorted into internal div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bratchan/zks5ojwh/4/) so far

```
$('.sortHolder').sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: ".sortHolder",
    items : ':not(.noSort)'
});

jQuery('.outer').sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: ".outer",
    items : ':not(.noSort)'
});
```

I assume I am missing one piece in my jquery

**So the goal is**

- Blue can go anywhere inside of divs
- Green does not move and can't be sorted
- Grey can only sort around another grey.
- Grey can NOT go into the green or blue

That is my issue the grey can go into the green and the large grey can go into other greys right now and that functionality is not what I want. That is the only issue I have right now. I'm probably missing something very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the code below and look at the playground, since I've changed a little bit classes on HTML as well: https://jsfiddle.net/zks5ojwh/5/

```
$('.grey').sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: ".grey",
    items : '.blue'
});

$('.sortHolder').sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    items: '.grey'
});
```

Comment: You are awesome!! Thank you!!

Comment: @Bratchan you are welcome. Also, if you satisfy with a solution, please, mark the answer.

Comment: Only issue I am having if you empty a green cell you can't, drag stuff back into it. I can drag them back into grey if it is empty though. So not sure why i can't do that with green

Comment: @Bratchan look at the updated version here https://jsfiddle.net/zks5ojwh/8/ 
Just add the code below, in order to be able to sort inside green, even if it's empty.
`$('.green').sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: ".green",
    items: '.blue'
});`

Comment: Cool!! Thankies